# Pandas reorder rows based on smallest to largest values in a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want to reorder rows based on column 9 value's in a data-frame (lowest value to largest) in ascending order for large dynamic data.

My data-frame:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  #Column values in this row
a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   0
a1  b1  c1  d1  dd1 ef  ggg hh  0.5
aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff ggg dcx -0.5
z   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   55
```

Desired ouput:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9 #Column values in this row
aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff ggg dcx -0.5
a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   0
a1  b1  c1  d1  dd1 ef  ggg hh  0.5
z   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   55
```

How do I reorder my data-frame rows so it appears as desired output from lowest number to highest.

```
df1.sort_values(['9'], ascending=[True])
```

Has no effect.

Comment: Did you forget to assign it to that dataframe i.e `df1= df1.sort_values...`

Comment: That wont rearange the rows. All you need is `df3 =  df3.sort_values(['9'])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need parameter `inplace=True`:

```
df1.sort_values('9', inplace=True)
print (df1)
     1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8     9
2  aaa  bbb  ccc  ddd  eee  fff  ggg  dcx  -0.5
0    a    b    c    d    e    f    g    h   0.0
1   a1   b1   c1   d1  dd1   ef  ggg   hh   0.5
3    z    b    c    d    e    f    g    h  55.0
```

Or assign back as commented `Dark`:

```
df1 = df1.sort_values('9')
print (df1)
     1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8     9
2  aaa  bbb  ccc  ddd  eee  fff  ggg  dcx  -0.5
0    a    b    c    d    e    f    g    h   0.0
1   a1   b1   c1   d1  dd1   ef  ggg   hh   0.5
3    z    b    c    d    e    f    g    h  55.0
```